# gitignore new file content not working

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .htaccess file in a repo and I cloned the repo in my local system, but now the .htaccess file needs to change. So I added .htaccess to .gitignore file. And when I do git status, it still showing .htaccess file modified and will be pushed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged .htaccess
```

It will tell git to assume that the file won't be changed for repo and won't be pushed.

To undo this at any time use this command :

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged .htaccess
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, to get the list of assume unchaged files, use this :

`git ls-files -v|grep '^h'`

Comment: I now that the result will be quite the same but in such a situation, you should use `--skip-worktree` instead of `--assume-unchanged`.